# Using !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $minCapacity) for multiple variables

Tags: php

What would be the best way of writing the below if statement more efficiently?

> ```
>         if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $min) || 
>             !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $max) ||
>             !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $c1) ||
>             !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $c2) ||
>             !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $c3) ||
>             !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $c4) ||
>             !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $c5) ||
>         )
>         {
>           echo 'Wrong value"
>           exit;
>         };
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Btw I am validating for integers.... whole numbers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$tests = array($min, $max, $c1, $c2, $c3, $c4, $c5);

if (count(preg_grep('/^\d+$/', $tests, PREG_GREP_INVERT)) > 0) {
  echo 'Wrong value';
  exit;
}
```

- [`preg_grep()` docs](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)
- Note that I have changed the regex to use the `\d` sequence instead of a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexp, just use `is_numeric` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php
or something like

```
is_int( $myvar + 0 )
```

Comment: I thought about this, but it would give false positives - the regex above requires all digits, `is_numeric()` accepts other forms of numeric representations.

Comment: That would work, and it may be `more efficient` as the OP requests, although there are two points about that: 1) You would have to ensure all value were cast to strings before being tested and 2) you would still either have to loop or write that very long condition. Neither of these two things are *problems*, but they are things to be aware of.

Comment: indeed, thanks for making those remarks - i just really like to see people to use less regular expressions when viable alternatives (which are almost always more efficient) exist

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a conceptual idea of how you can test input variables in a much neater way.

```
switch(false)
{
    case is_int($min):
    case is_int($max):
    case is_int($c1):
    case is_int($c2):
    case is_int($c3):
    case is_int($c4):
    case is_int($c5):
        echo "Wrong value";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```